# Is editline tab completion supposed to work?

Tags: c, readline

Is there a way for libedit (editline) to do tab completion if I use editline for a small shell? It seems that `rl_parse_and_bind` is not available if I include `histedit.h` - why doesn't it work?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sigaction sh;
    /* char *shell_prompt[100];*/
    sh.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sh.sa_mask);
    sh.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sh, NULL);
    int index = 0;
    int i;
    EditLine *el = el_init(argv[0], stdin, stdout, stderr);
    el_set(el, EL_PROMPT_ESC, &prompt, '\1');
    el_set(el, EL_EDITOR, "emacs");
    rl_parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete");
    HistEvent ev;
    History *myhistory;
    while (1) {
        index = 0;
        i = getopt_long(argc, argv, "p:vh",
                        options, &index);
        if (i == -1)
            break;
        switch (i) {
            case 'p': {
                /* store_parameter(optarg); */
                break;
            }
            case 'v': {
                printf("OpenShell version 0.1(a)\n");
                printf("Version: %s\n", VERSION);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            }
            case 'h': {
                printf("Usage: ./shell\n");
                /*print_help();*/
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            }
            default: {
                /* fprintf(stderr, "Error (%s): unrecognized option.\n", __FUNCTION__);*/
                /* print_help();*/
                return 1;/*RETURN_FAILURE;*/

            }
        }
    }
    getPath();
    myhistory = history_init();
    if (myhistory == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "history could not be initialized\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* Set the size of the history */
    history(myhistory, &ev, H_SETSIZE, 800);

    /* This sets up the call back functions for history functionality */
    el_set(el, EL_HIST, history, myhistory);

    while (1) {
        int count;
        char const *line = el_gets(el, &count);
        char *pos;
        if (line && (pos = strchr(line, '\n')) != NULL)
            *pos = '\0';
        if (line && count > 0)
            command(line);
        /* In order to use our history we have to explicitly add commands
   to the history */
        if (count > 0) {
            history(myhistory, &ev, H_ENTER, line);
        }
    }
    el_end(el);
    return 0;
}
```

Now this is how my relevant headers look and it seems to work both with OpenBSD and Ubuntu:

```
#include <histedit.h>
#ifdef linux
#include <editline/readline.h>
#endif
#ifdef __OpenBSD__
#include <readline/readline.h>
#endif
```

Comment: It surely supposed to work, to use `rl_parse_and_bind` include `readline.h`, why not ask a specific question?

Comment: @fluter It failed for me because I mix up 'editline` and `readline`. If I only include `histedit.h` then `rs_parse_and_bind` is not available and `readline.h` I include as `#include <readline/readline.h>` is that right? I'm not sure what includes to use if I want the code to work and compile both with OpenBSD and Ubuntu.

Comment: To use it you should `#include <readline/readline.h>`.

Comment: BTW are you on BSD on Linux?

Comment: @fluter Yes I like BSD. I run OpenBSD and FreeBSD in virtualboxes.

Comment: Good to know you like and run 2 BSDs though! :)

Comment: @fluter BSD is very cool! If I have to choose just one I choose BSD out of principle...but it works very well in Virtual Box. I also tried DragonflyBSD. Now from your conditional includes I'm starting to understand. The reason I did this was to have the same code for both BSD and Linux, but that might be impossible. I can go for conditional includes.

Comment: Have you tried adding `#include <editline/readline.h>` to the source?

Comment: @fluter Yes, It compiles but there are many different versions. I'd like to use the BSD version. I'm not sure which headers to include when there's both `editline` and 'readline`. Right now it works though on both OpenBSD and Ubuntu without a conditional include, that was my goal to not have conditional includes.

Comment: Since you are using libedit, you should `#include <editline/readline.h> and #include <histedit.h>`.

Comment: But I can't resolve the variable `rl_parse_and_bind` no matter what I include.

Comment: `rl_parse_and_bind` is in `editline/readline.h` on my case, and you need to add `-ledit -ltinfo` to the linker when building. Do you still see the problem if you do this?

Comment: Ok, yes it was the condition of the include that seemed to not work. It is something else that "`Linux`" for the condition of the header. OpenBSD has `readline/readline.h` while Ubuntu has editline.

Comment: Can you post the relevant lines of the condition of the header? I don't see it on my version of libedit.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this seemed to work: `#ifdef linux
#include <editline/readline.h>
#endif
#ifdef __OpenBSD__
#include <readline/readline.h>
#endif`

Comment: Yeah, it should work!

Comment: @fluter If you want to test the code it is here https://github.com/montao/openshell Now the includes work on both BSD and Linux!

Comment: Glad to know it works, since we are having a solution, I'm adding an answer to this post.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322148/posts-of-the-serial-votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was depending on the system, some headers are not available, so need to check includes with conditionals.

```
#if defined(__linux__) // can also use Linux here
#include <editline/readline.h>
#elif defined(__OpenBSD__)
#include <readline/readline.h>
#endif
```